# Display Attribute in Magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created a new attribute as location through admin panel , now i have to show that attribute on product page? So please help me how to add the location on page.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution :-

Step 1:- Please visit here:- http://nimb.ws/lS9zmJ

Step 2:- After step 1, go to`app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml`

add code `<?php echo $_product->getLocation() ; ?>`  on this file where you want to show this attribute.

Step 3:- Now go to product detail page & you'll see your attribute value on this page, for the demo please visit here:- http://nimb.ws/WNv1J4